# how to use v-model in nested custom components in vue.js?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

How can I use v-model for two level deep nested components?
e.g. in HTML

```
<opening-hr-field v-model="day"> </opening-hr-field>
```

here `day` is an object e.g. `{is24Open: true, startTime: '5:00 PM'}`

JS template

```
<template type="text/x-template" id="opening-hr-field-template">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="value.is24Open"> 24 hour
     <time-select v-model = "value.startTime"></time-select>
  </div>
</template>

<template  type="text/x-template" id="time-select-template">
  <select :value="value" 
    v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
    <option v-for="t in getHours()">
      {{ t }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>
```

Here, I have two level deep v-model. How can I propagate the emit from 2nd template to first template and all way up to the parent? Can you please show me an example?

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken, you're talking about you have two nest templates, but they are modifying the same variable??

Comment: This question was posted back in 2017 which is long before the other question was posted. If there is any similarity, the other question is a duplicate.